# How to disable AssemblyPlugin for the default root project only?

Tags: sbt

Say I have the following multi-project structure:

```
my-project/
├── build.sbt
├── app1/
├── app2/
├── app3/
├── sharedA/
└── sharedB/
```

I use [sbt-assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly) to create fat JARs for the *app* subprojects. The *shared* subprojects are just library code so I disable **AssemblyPlugin** for those.

I use the [default root project](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Multi-Project.html#Default+root+project) syntax so the subprojects are aggregated without me having to list them all out.

```
name := "my-project"

lazy val app1 = (project in file("app1"))
  .dependsOn(sharedA)

lazy val app2 = (project in file("app2"))
  .dependsOn(sharedB)

lazy val app3 = (project in file("app3"))
  .dependsOn(sharedA, sharedB)

lazy val sharedA = (project in file("sharedA"))
  .disablePlugins(AssemblyPlugin)

lazy val sharedB = (project in file("sharedB"))
  .disablePlugins(AssemblyPlugin)
```

When I run `sbt assembly`, this mostly works: I get assembly jars for the *app*s and none for the *shared*s. However, I also get a **my-project-assembly.jar** which I don't need. How do I disable this?

If I disable from the top

```
name := "my-project"
disablePlugins(AssemblyPlugin)

...
```

Then the plugin is disabled completely, even for subprojects.

I know I can explicitly declare a root project, and this works:

```
lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .aggregate(app1, app2, app3, sharedA, sharedB)
  .disablePlugins(AssemblyPlugin)

...
```

But, in reality, there can be a lot of subprojects so I would like to stick to the *default root project* style.

Answer (score 0):

If you discard the paths in the `assemblyMergeStrategy` i think it will run as you wish.

```
assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := { 

    case PathList("sharedA", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("sharedB", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
    ...

}
```